# Expectation of Gaussian random vector over a subspace

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a Gaussian random vector, distributed as $\boldsymbol{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \sigma^2 \boldsymbol{I}_d)$, where $\boldsymbol{I}_d$ is an identity matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. We also assume $\|\boldsymbol{\mu}\|_{\ell_2} = 1$. Given a subspace $\mathcal{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, I want to upper bound the Euclidean norm $\|\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{x}~|~ \mathcal{R}]\|_{\ell_2}$.

Comment: What properties of $\mathcal{R}$ do you want to use for the bound? Since $x$ is just a collection of $d$ independent random variables and the Norm is their root sum of squares, consider first solving this problem for $d=1.$

Comment: Suppose $\mathcal{R}$ is a subsapce.

Comment: Yes?  That doesn't seem to provide any further guidance concerning what you're looking for.

Comment: Given a vector $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\boldsymbol{v} >0$, I  want to upper bound $\|\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{x}~(\text{sgn}(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{\mu}) - \text{sgn}(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{v}))]\|_{\ell_2}$. Here $\text{sgn}(\alpha)$ is equal to $+1$ if $\alpha \geq 0$ and it is equal to $-1$ otherwise. To simplify this, I am asking a for a general subspace but I am interested in the region where $\text{sgn}(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{\mu}) \neq \text{sgn}(\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{v})$. Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution.

Comment: I see you have asked this on multiple sites. Please choose where you want to ask.

Comment: I have deleted from other cites. This is my first time so I didn't realize it is the same community. Thanks for your information!